# How can I get the RewriteCond flag "-f" to recognise already-rewritten files?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

We're currently migrating our monstrous legacy PHP application to PHRoute - it's made up of around ten or twenty thousand top level scripts. We've spiked a few isolated pages, but now I'm trying to integrate it with the whole system.

I'm using the following rewrite rules to exclude any existing files and directories from being re-routed, so it doesn't try to route any of the existing top level scripts.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This works fine with one exception: for multi-tenancy/custom branding reasons we have rewrite rules for our client-specific files like logos, CSS, etc. The conditions of the router rewrite rules don't pick up the rewritten client files, and so it tries to re-route, for example, `static/theme.css` when it should just rewrite it to `/clients/[client]/css/theme.css` and skip the router entirely.

How can I adjust the above rules to pick up the rewritten files as a "real" file (`-f`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the `[L]` or `[last]` flag from the client specific file rewrites, which meant the router rules were running against the original URL (`static/theme.css`) instead of the rewritten one (`/clients/[client]/css/theme.css`).

Adding the `L` flag means it now processes the client rewrite immediately instead of waiting until the end. So by the time it gets to the router rewrites it's now checking against the real file location, and thus successfully recognises the real file.

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l